# Дайте совет по CSS (оптимизация сайта под разрешения экрана)

Tags: html, css

Если я буду использовать вот такой код

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation: portrait) and 
(max-width:640px), projection" "href=»style.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation: portrait) and 
(max-width:1024px), projection" "href=»style.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation: portrait) and 
(min-width:1280px), projection" "href=»style.css" />
```

То браузер будет загружать все CSS файлы или только под нужное разрешение?

Если да, то подскажите решение, я буду очень признателен

Comment: я так не извращаюсь , проще обычный медиа запрос `@media screen and ( ){/*style*/}`

Comment: Так необходимо все стили в @media переносить?

Comment: @TomasRendl конечно

Comment: У меня просто там JS много где, и удобнее было бы сделать, так как я описал. Но переживая за скорость и вес трафика страниц пользователей.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо попробую через @media screen реализовать шаблон

Comment: Но всё же хотелось бы получить ответ

Comment: какой вас ответ интересует ? `@media` удобнее и именно такая реализация получила огромную долю при применении

Comment: Загружает ли он весь CSS код или мне придётся это через php делать

Comment: весь загружается, какой напишите такой и будет , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries